# How do we return the value of a variable whose value is assigned inside an IF statement?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have recently been making a calculator project and I have run into a small problem.

```
   internal static float Answer_Descision(string[] Data, float num1, float num2, string operand) 
   {
        string operand_types = ["*", "+", "/", "pwr", "-"];
        float ans;
        int Lenth_Of_Data = Data.Length;
        bool Help = Data[1] == "Help";
        if (Lenth_Of_Data == 1 && Help)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The availible operands as of version 1.2 of the calculator are:\n1. \"+\"\n2. \"-\"\n3. \"*\"\n4. \"/\"\n5. \"pwr\"\n");
        }
        else if(operand == operand_types)
        { 
            ans = Operation_Descision(num1, operand, num2);
        }
        return ans;
   }
```

I basically want to assign a value to the variable "ans" inside the if statement.

But now when I do this it displays the following error for the return word:
 Use of unassigned variable "ans".

I want to know, how to assign the value of ans to it inside the if statement?

Comment: You should do `float ans = 0f;`

Comment: Or if there is no default/reserved value to return in that case, change the types to nullable float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not assigned any value to `ans` variable at the time of defining it.

Assign default value to the variable where you are defining it.

```
float ans = 0f;  //Assign default vale
```

---

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables)

> A variable must be **definitely assigned** [(Definite assignment)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#definite-assignment) before 
>   its value can be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Prasad, you must assign a value to the `ans` variable.

You can do it when you declare the variable:

```cs
float ans = 0f;
```

Or in your `if`, and don't forget the `else` statement as well. Thanks @dxiv for pointing this out.

```cs
if (Lenth_Of_Data == 1 && Help)
{
    ans = 0f;
    Console.WriteLine("The availible operands as of version 1.2 of the calculator are:\n1. \"+\"\n2. \"-\"\n3. \"*\"\n4. \"/\"\n5. \"pwr\"\n");
}
else if
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    ans = 0f;
}
```

Note you can use `0` or `0f` as a value, since you are explicitly declaring the variable as a `float`.

If you were to use `var` instead, you need to specify `0f` explicitly. Thus all these ways of declaring and assigning the `ans` are valid:

```cs
var ans = 0f;
float ans = 0;
float ans = 0.0;
float ans = 0f;
```